# Battery 601 error.

Tags: laptop, battery

I'm using a HP Pavilion TouchSmart Laptop, core i3. 
On starting my laptop today after it drained out of battery, I got a message that it needs to be replaced as it is below the usual power capacity. 
My laptop does not function for more than an hour without being plugged in. And I know that I need to replace the battery.

However, my only question is, if I replace the battery are there possibilities of losing all the content from my laptop?

And is it safe to stretch it out for another 15 days and then change the battery of the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to the internal BIOS/CMOS battery, not the big battery that powers your laptop. You need to replace it.

You don't lose any data if you change the battery (either of them).